# Extract values from webpages

Tags: r

Is it possible to get specific values from a url and save them to a csv?

I have a txt files with one column with urls like this

I try to make to collect values such as the value of rewards and the number of backers. The final file should have two columns like the following

```
10,15,30,50     17,9,9
```

Comment: They don't have a public API, so you'd have to scrape it.

Comment: @ceejayoz please if it is possible could you give me an example?

Comment: Downvote for "does not show any research effort". Have you looked for help on this, because there's lots out there. Try the R Web Technologies Task View (google for that if you don't know what it is).

Comment: You any anyone who helps you are in violation of Section 3 of Kickstarter's Terms of Service - https://www.kickstarter.com/terms-of-use and are subject to legal action by them.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution using `rvest` package:

```
library(rvest)
url.parse<-read_html("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description")

reward<-url.parse%>%
 html_nodes("h5")%>%
 html_text(trim=TRUE)
reward
[1] "$10 reward" "$15 reward" "$30 reward" "$50 reward"

 backers<-url.parse%>%
 html_nodes("span.num-backers.mr1")%>%
 html_text(trim=TRUE)

backers
[1] "17 backers" "9 backers"  "9 backers"  "30 backers"
```

If you want both in one dataframe:

```
df1<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(c("span.num-backers.mr1","h5"),
                     function(i) {
                        url.parse %>%
                             html_nodes(i) %>%
                             html_text(trim=TRUE)
                     })))
df1

   X1         X2
1 17 backers $10 reward
2  9 backers $15 reward
3  9 backers $30 reward
4 30 backers $50 reward
```

If you have a list of urls, you can proceed as follows:

```
url_kick<-c("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description","https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured")
data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(url_kick,function(url_name){
    kk<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,lapply(c("span.num-backers.mr1","h5"),
                                        function(i) {
                                            read_html(url_name) %>%
                                                html_nodes(i) %>%
                                                html_text(trim=TRUE)
                                        })))
    return(cbind(kk,urlname=url_name))})))
          X1                                  X2                                                                                                      urlname
1  17 backers                          $10 reward                                  https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description
2   9 backers                          $15 reward                                  https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description
3   9 backers                          $30 reward                                  https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description
4  30 backers                          $50 reward                                  https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description
5    1 backer                         Josh Ginter https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
6    1 backer              Project by Josh Ginter https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
7   3 backers   Pledge $1 or more\n\nAbout $1 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
8   3 backers                        About $1 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
9   3 backers   Pledge $1 or more\n\nAbout $1 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
10  3 backers                        About $1 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
11  6 backers   Pledge $5 or more\n\nAbout $5 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
12  6 backers                        About $5 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
13   1 backer   Pledge $5 or more\n\nAbout $5 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
14   1 backer                        About $5 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
15  3 backers Pledge $10 or more\n\nAbout $10 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
16  3 backers                       About $10 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
17  3 backers Pledge $10 or more\n\nAbout $10 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
18  3 backers                       About $10 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
19  6 backers Pledge $25 or more\n\nAbout $25 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
20  6 backers                       About $25 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
21   1 backer Pledge $25 or more\n\nAbout $25 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
22   1 backer                       About $25 USD https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1685845978/creature-and-hand-1-an-accordion-comic?ref=category_featured
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will test it and come back. Is it possible to make it for a list of urls?

Comment: Yes, you can use `lapply` to run a list of urls. Please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer after it worked for you.

Comment: @angs looping over a list is a basic R operation that you would do well to learn about rather than asking us to spoonfeed you. There's lots of R documentation out there, take some time to learn from those and *then* ask here.

Comment: @user227710 thank you very much. I tried the second solution with sapply it gives me back this Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'url.parse' not found

Comment: No problem. You have to also use `url.parse<-read_html("https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1154444340/god-in-new-york/description")` for the second solution.

Comment: It woks perfect but I have a last question do you believe it could be possible to make the output as I include in my question because if I add a list with urls I can't understand which values go to the first url, which values go to the second etc. Thank you

Comment: The values go in the order you include them in the list. Additionally, you can include the website name as columns. Please see my updates in teh answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I could upvote your post and I make it. I don't know what else I could do in order to thank you. Just something I note in the results. The column urlname is perfect but the X1 and X2 columns have the values of the first url, the values are repeated in every new url.

Comment: No problem. I have updated the answer. But, you should know the two websites are not designed in the same way and hence you will not get what you want. Please read this [tutorial](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/11/24/rvest-easy-web-scraping-with-r/) to understand what I have been doing so far.